# Does anyone consider Being a primitive, unanalyzable, term?

Tags: ontology, existentialism, heidegger, being-and-time, being

Does anyone say that Being is a primitive, unanalyzable, term?

That probably would make *Being and Time* the greatest work of nonsense of all time. I certainly feel able to imagine that Being is unanalyzable, even that *Being and Time* is almost entirely nonsense. Has Heidegger or any Heideggerian responded to any such complaint?

Comment: This complaint is easily countered regardless of the subject. Points and lines in Euclid are primitive, unanalyzable terms, yet the Elements are hardly nonsense. Most interesting concepts are explicated not by analysis into primitives, but by analysis of the interrelationships they enter, and their consequences. This realization is the big difference between the Aristotelian and modern analysis.

Comment: The whole point of the book is that it is about Being understanding itself, so the premise seems problematic in the first place: Being **is** human life in time (and cultural background)... That being said, Hölderlin indeed argued for Being as a primitive and unanalysable term, but both Being and "unanalysable" have a different meaning in that context

Comment: I'm not sure who says what, but the idea that the primitive unalayzable term transcends the being/non-being distinction is common. “In the Beginning … Then neither Being nor Not-being was," (The Rig-Veda).

Comment: oh ok i thought being and time was explicitly trying to analyze or find the meaning of Being? @Conifold does the elements being "what is the meaning of a point"?

Comment: In a sense, yes, it is revealed in the role points play in Euclid's theorems, which sharpens the pre-existent intuitions. Heidegger's subject is, obviously, much more complex, but he too has the "being" enter various contexts (being-here, etc.) to evoke and sharpen the pre-philosophical grasp of the word.

Comment: In the context of the question, either "Being" and all other terms are primitive, unanalyzable, or other all are not primitive and analyzable. Language is a circular self-dependent set of terms, as well as knowledge can be a circular self-dependent set of concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by considering the *existence as quantification* point of view. In this case, "*X* exists," can be paraphrased as, "There is at least 1 *X*" (or, if we want to allow degenerate amounts, "There are not 0-many *X*s"). Seems simple enough; and quantification might seem qualitatively primitive (insofar as the quantitative-qualitative distinction itself is relevant to the whole question of conceptual break-down analysis).

"Alas," this is not quite so. Consider the [Stanford EP article on quantifiers and quantification overall](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quantification/). There are about 30+ sections/subsections in this article. The SEP also contains entries focusing on [generalized quantifiers](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/generalized-quantifiers/) or [plural quantification](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plural-quant/). So it turns out that the notion of quantities-as-existence/quantities-*of*-existence, if not "analyzable" in the break-down sense, certainly can be "analyzed into" a plenum of further mysteries. (With respect to general quantifiers, there is an option where we would have *infinitely many* special quantifiers in place, e.g. as assigned their value from various transfinite cardinals. The types of sets in the higher infinite could be construed as higher forms of existence, as quantification, itself.}

And so that's just starting with the quantification view (c.f. problems with the related, or perhaps (ultimately) equivalent, concept of [reference](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/reference/)). Consider modal logic, now. Aren't possibility and necessity in roughly the same category as actuality? But is actuality different from existence? [Meinongianism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/existence/#Mei) is (in)famous for two subcategories of being/existence/actuality, one involving an existence-type *predicate* and the other just being(!) the existential quantifier; or we might speak of broader ["degrees of existence"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/abs/time-reality-and-experience/time-and-degrees-of-existence-a-theory-of-degree-presentism/). And [actualists](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/actualism/) will wage war across the multiverse with possibilists until all other possible-worlds talk goes down in flames, if need be.

Note that Kant's theory of modality epiphenomenalizes not only being/existence directly, but the possible and necessary forms of this to boot. He would not have countenanced ontological arguments from God's supposed self-necessity anymore than he countenanced such arguments as were grounded on God's supposed self-actuality. Regardless of whether these issues are truly resolved by Kant/his inheritors, the very question of how modal predicates work (substantially or epiphenomenally, so to say) adds depth to the "analysis" of existence. Moreso when with Meinong we layer actuality, or with fringe logicians of our day we [nontrivially iterate the modal operators.](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/p/phimp/3521354.0011.003/--iterated-modalities-meaning-and-a-priori-knowledge?view=image)

A last moment of reflection: the *uncreatable*/*uncreated*/*created* trichotomy also seems to bear on (or be borne upon by) the "category" of generic existence. That is, if the concept of existence is an essentially self-pluralizing concept, or such as to have all these many and varied natures to its pure name, then I would think the theistic existence-predicates might be situated in the entire array, though where and how exactly is not totally clear to me, right now. Note that it is not immediate to the creation-theoretic trichotomy as displayed that it also incorporates the concepts of *destructible and indestructible being* into their representation; but note that *destroying the destruction of something* could also be styled a *recreation of* said thing.

So the concept of destruction is also an analyzable "content" of our reflection on the concept of existence, with all the dark complexity that it should bring to our questions.

Comment: Indeed everything is further analyzable in some sense as the ancient famous [Vajra sutra](http://www.cttbusa.org/vajra/vajrasutra2.asp.html) hinted long ago: *The perfection of physical form is spoken of by the Tathagata as no perfection of physical form, therefore it is called the perfection of physical form....*

Answer (score 1):

Derrida answers this while on the subject of history, in *Heidegger: The Question of Being and History*, page 209

> Being in general is nothing, but the multiplicity of beings and of
> types of beings could not be thought *as such*, beings could not be
> thought as such without pre-comprehension at least of the meaning of
> being in general.

And the fuller context of the quote.

> each determinate historicity, each determinate historial line, has its
> irreducible originality, its own movement and temporal rhythm: the
> historicity of equipment, of technology, the historicity of
> institutions, the historicity of works of art, and within the
> historicity of art, the historicity of different types of art, and so
> on. ... To speak of historicity in general is not to affirm that there
> is a general history; it is to affirm that there is a meaning to
> historicity, not a meaning of history, but a meaning of historicity
> without which I could not even speak of determinate historicities. ...
> To speak of a meaning of historicity in general is no more to affirm
> that there is a general history than to speak of the meaning or the
> question of the meaning of being in general signifies for the
> beingness of Being in general. Being in general is nothing, but the
> multiplicity of beings and of types of beings could not be thought *as
> such*, beings could not be thought as such without pre-comprehension
> at least of the meaning of being in general.
>
> So, just as there is meaning of being, just as the meaning of being
> comes about only because *Da-sein* ek-sists, so the historicity of
> history and therefore of histor*ies* only comes about because *Dasein*
> produces it and is produced (both things have to be said at once) in
> the historicity of its *In-der-Welt-sein*. Precomprehended meaning of
> historicity and not of history in general.

Furthermore in Heidegger's *Contributions to Philosophy (of the Event)* 270 The essence of beyng, p381

> Beyng is nothing "in itself" and nothing "for" a "subject." Only
> beingness can appear as this sort of an "in itself" and can do so only
> in the form of an effete φύσις [phusis/nature], i.e., as ίδἐα, the καθ' αὐτό ["for
> itself"], something represented, an object. An extreme confinement in
> objectivity befalls all attempts to find "being" and its
> "determinations" (categories) in the manner of something objectively
> present.

Comment: Well, if Heidegger's work is nonsense, he seems to be in good company with Derrida. I remember in my teens being intensely interested in the writing of Bertrand Russell- his prose was so lucid. Heidegger and the like seem to sprout meaningless verbiage.

Comment: @MarcoOcram It's ironic that Derrida's book from which the above quote is taken [is described](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/26195574-heidegger) as "an almost surgical reading of [Heidegger's] notoriously difficult text, marrying pedagogical clarity with patient rigor and **acting as a lucid guide** through the thickets of Heidegger’s prose." In your defence however, I *have* taken the quote abruptly out of context: re. "historicity" etc. As Derrida goes, *The Question of Being & History* is one of his more straightforward presentations.

Comment: cheers! You might enjoy the following homage to Jacques...https://www.theawfulauthor.com/blog-1/2021/7/3/vive-la-diffrence

Comment: Separately, Chris, if you spot this, I tried to tag your name @ChrisDegnen at the start of my previous comment but it was automatically expunged whenever I saved it. Any idea why?

Comment: @MarcoOcram Lol re. scones. As the author of the answer I get alerted to comments so the tag is unnecessary.