# What is 'Being'?

Tags: being-and-time, being

So far, being is what beings do, maybe. What is it? E.g. as the Bishop of Berkeley might align with, (Being & Time, page 61)

> Being, as the basic theme of philosophy, is no class or genus of
> entities; yet it pertains to every entity. Its 'universality' is to
> be sought higher up. Being and the structure of Being lie beyond every
> entity and every possible character which an entity may possess.

Comment: "Being" is not the basic theme of philosophy, but only the basic topic of *metaphysics*, which of course is the "first philosophy", and probably the philosophy Berkeley had in mind. But "What is Being?" has been pondered about for quite a long time. Any particular reason you chose to bring up Berkeley, rather than Aristotle, or Sartre, or any philosopher in between?

Comment: Hi Frank, I'm seeking to build on my own answer [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/92639/5154).  I threw in Berkeley for kicks ;-)

Comment: It could be said that all philosophy is about being, within this aboutness whether it's there or here, in-itself or for-itself, dasein or transcendental, exists or exists not, randomly decoded images or compressively encoded binary string with low algorithmic entropy. Each thing, as far as it can by its own power, strives to persevere in its being which unavoidably consists of its actions and passions constituting the quidity of the said being...